# Excel VBA with API Trouble

Tags: api, vba, excel

So I'm having trouble trying to get a method from an API to run correctly. Documentation says that the method has the following:

```vb
updateMethod(Object, String, Int)
```

The object is the worksheet or workbook that holds the item to be updated. The String is the name of the item, and the Int is what type of update will take place.

The method has to actually be used with a Boolean, as it will return `True` if updated and `False` if not:

wasUpdated = api.updateMethod(Object, String, Int)

So my code example is:

```vb
Function TestUpdate()

    Dim wasUpdated As Boolean
    Dim Container As Object
    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim refreshType As Integer

    Set Container = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    RangeName = "RangeTest"
    refreshType = 0

    wasUpdated = api.updateMethod(Container, RangeName, refreshType)

    If wasUpdate = True Then
        MsgBox "Updated"
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed"
    End If

End Function
```

I keep getting a Runtime-Error 424 on the `wasUpdate = ...` saying "Object Required". Am I not defining the Object correctly? Or is this a possible issue with the API itself and I need to contact the company?

Thanks

Comment: Is the API looking specifically for a `Worksheet Object`? If so, change `Dim Container As Object` to `Dim Container as Worksheet`

Comment: Use `Option Explicit` at the top of your module.

You're storing the return value of your function call to `wasUpdated`, and then try to read `wasUpdate`. Note the missing letter.

Comment: How and where is `api` declared/assigned?

Comment: @SiddharthRout : Not sure I can put it out there, but it is an api for ACNielsen data pulling.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman : Changed that, still getting same error.

Comment: @DanielCook : Thanks for catching that. Still didn't solve the issue.

Comment: @TimWilliams : Tools -> References in the Excel VB window.

Comment: @JH - you still need to create that API object using `New` or `CreateObject`

Comment: @TimWilliams That was it. Thanks a lot. I'll post full answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit goes to @TimWilliams

The problem was not declaring an API object, had nothing to do with the container object.

```
Function TestUpdate()

    Dim wasUpdated As Boolean
    Dim Container As Worksheet
    Dim RangeName As String
    Dim refreshType As Integer
    Dim apiUpdateObject As Object
    Dim apiObject As Object

    Set apiObject = CreateObject("ApiDLL.Object")
    Set apiObject.ParentApp = ActiveWorkbook.Application

    Set apiUpdateObject = apiObject.UpdateMethod
    Set Container = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    RangeName = "RangeTest"
    refreshType = 0

    wasUpdated = apiUpdateObject.UpdateNRange(Container, RangeName, refreshType)

    If wasUpdated = True Then
        MsgBox "Updated"
    Else
        MsgBox "Failed"
    End If

End Function
```

Thanks for the help guys.